# Showing that the differentiation operator is linear on $C([0,1])$ but not bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

This one seemed a little too straightforward and there's a really minor point that's making me worry that my solution is wrong.

Let $D:C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1])$ denote the differentiation operator.

Showing linearity is easy, so I'm omitting it from here.

If $D$ were bounded, then there would be some $c$ such that $||D(f)||\leq c||f||$, where $||g||=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|g(x)|$.

However, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\in C([0,1])$, but $D(f)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is unbounded. Thus there is no $c$ such that $||D(f)||\leq c||f||$.

My concern is that, since $D(f)$ is unbounded, $||D(f)||$ isn't even defined. However, the question as stated explicitly asks us to show the differentiation operator from $D:C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1])$ is unbounded.

Does this mean that I should just restrict myself to functions whose derivative is continuous on $[0,1]$? Or is my solution valid?

Comment: It suffices to show that no such $c$ exists for a sequence. For instance, you could take the sequence $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x+\tfrac{1}{n}}$ whose derivative on $[0,1]$ is bounded but diverges in the limit. More rigorously, assume $c$ exists and get a contradiction for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Not every continuous function is differentiable : so probably the domain consists of all continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$? That rules out $\sqrt x$ even belonging in the domain.

Comment: By the extreme value theorem, the norm of every vector in $C([0, 1])$ should be finite, so something in your argument is wrong ($\sqrt{x}$ is not even right-differentiable at $x=0$). Perhaps you mean to use the space $C^\infty([0, 1])$ of infinitely differentiable functions instead. The usual trick after that is to find for each $M \geq 0$, a function $f$ such that $\lVert D(f) \rVert \geq M$, or something similar.

Comment: You could look at the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n$, for which $\|D(f_n)\| = n$

Comment: What $D$ are you talking about? Differentiation does not map $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x}$ does not count as being in the domain because its derivative is not in $C[0,1]$. The domain should consist of continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$.

A sequence of functions that will prove that $D$ is unbounded is $\{ x^n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Every element of this sequence has norm $1$. But $D(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$ has norm $n$. So $D : \mathcal{D}(D)\subset C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ is not bounded.

Comment: +1. Your A appeared while I was typing mine. I type verrrrrrrry slowly.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : :) I started typing almost 50 years ago.

Comment: That's about how long it takes me for one A.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : At least you have your sense of humor. I think I've lost that. :)

Answer (score 1):

$D(f)=f'$ when $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$ but we don't know what $D(\sqrt x)$ is, because $\sqrt x$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. We do know that we cannot have $D(\sqrt x)=1/\sqrt x$ for every $x\in (0,1],$ as that would make $D(\sqrt x)$ discontinuous at $x=0,$ which would imply $D(\sqrt x)\not \in C[0,1].$

If $f_n(x)=x^n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ then $\|f_n\|=1$ and $\|D(f_n)\|=\|f'_n\|=n.$

Comment: $C([0,1])$ is often denoted as $C[0,1]$ for convenience.

Comment: Returned the favor with +1